# Making two extension functions into one

Tags: c#

I have two extension functions, which operates on `List<int>` and `List<string>`.

```
public static string StringTokenizr(this List<int> list, NpStringTokenizrType type, string splitter = ",")
{
    return string.Join(",", list.ConvertAll(name => string.Format(type == NpStringTokenizrType.StringLike ? "'{0}'" : "{0}", name.ToString().Replace("'", "\\'"))));
}

public static string StringTokenizr(this List<string> list, NpStringTokenizrType type, string splitter = ",")
{
    return string.Join(",", list.ConvertAll(name => string.Format(type == NpStringTokenizrType.StringLike ? "'{0}'" : "{0}", name.ToString().Replace("'", "\\'"))));
}
```

Is there any way to make it more generic so that it can just be one function?

Comment: Could you not use Generic Type arguments i.e: List<T>

Answer (score 3):

Make your method generic:

```
public static string StringTokenizr<T>(
       this List<T> list, 
       NpStringTokenizrType type, 
       string splitter = ",")
{
   return string.Join(",", list.ConvertAll(name => string.Format(type == NpStringTokenizrType.StringLike ? "'{0}'" : "{0}", name.ToString().Replace("'", "\\'"))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can make it general, but this function will not be limited to int and string it will accept other types

```
public static string StringTokenizr<T>(this List<T> list, NpStringTokenizrType type, string splitter = ",")
{
    return string.Join(",", list.ConvertAll(name => string.Format(type == NpStringTokenizrType.StringLike ? "'{0}'" : "{0}", name.ToString().Replace("'", "\\'"))));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either use generic Type arguments like `List<T>` and check the type within the body of the function or cast the `List` as a `string` coming into the function.